# how to add class in two place of menu with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
 <div class="leftside-navigation">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
        <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class=" fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                <span>Charts</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="morris.html">Morris</a></li>
                <li><a href="chartjs.html">Chartjs</a></li>
                <li><a href="sdad.sas">Flot Charts</a></li>
                <li><a href="c3_chart.html">C3 Chart</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class=" fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                <span>Maps</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="google_map.html">Google Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="test.php">Vector Map</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class="fa fa-glass"></i>
                <span>Extra</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="lock_screen.html">Lock Screen</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="invoice.html">Invoice</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing_table.html">Pricing Table</a></li>
                <li><a href="timeline.html">Timeline</a></li>                    
                <li><a href="qqw.qq">Media Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="404.html">404 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="500.html">500 Error</a></li>
                <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="login.html">
                <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <span>Login Page</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul></div>
```

I have a menu like above How can I put class="active" in two place like below with jquery.

Example:-
     
            
   .
   .
   .

```
<li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;" class="active">
                <i class=" fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                <span>Maps</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="sub">
                <li><a href="google_map.html">Google Map</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="vector_map.html">Vector Map</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

.
  .
  .

That means need to add class="active" in two place according to the url link on browser. in this example the url link is http://test.com/testproject/vector_map.html.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding class for second li using jquery

```
$("ul.sub li:eq(1)").addClass("active");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdpve0do/)

Comment: Thank you JqueryKing. I got my answer. Rocking... :)

Comment: I have a long list of the same <li></li> i mentioned above. If I clicked vector_map.html link  then <li><a href="vector_map.html">Vector Map</a></li> will become <li class="active"><a href="vector_map.html">Vector Map</a></li> and corresponding <a href="javascript:;">
                <i class=" fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                <span>Maps</span>
            </a> will become <a href="javascript:;" class="active">
                <i class=" fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
                <span>Maps</span>
            </a>. a bit problem I am still facing. Mr. JqueryKing.

Comment: Hi jqueryKing please see I have edited my main post a bit to understand the problem. If you have any doubt please let me know I will explain again. Please help me.

Comment: I tried with below one <script>

    var activeurl = window.location.pathname;
    $('#nav-accordion a[href="'+activeurl+'"] li.sub-menu a:eq(0)').addClass("active");
</script> but not working properly